# Moving folder to different location but only looking at first five characters

Tags: batch-file, tags, filenames, move

I need to move a particualar folder to a differnet location. Example C:\Test\Test2\ABCDEFGHI. I can only look at the first five characters i.e ABCDE of the folder name as the rest of the name changes daily. Any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have some foldername...

```
@echo off
set foldername=C:\Test\Test2\ABCDEFGHI
call :GetFolderName5 "%foldername%"
pause
goto :eof

:GetFolderName5
set folder5chr=%~n1
set folder5chr=%~dp1%folder5chr:~0,5%
echo.%folder5chr%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats great, thanks for your reply. What I now need to do is incorporate this into more code.

When I find this folder beginning with ABCDE, then I need to copy it to another location. Here is what I have been doing already but using a specific folder name i.e. (ECU). In the first part I am also zipping any folder with the name "Logfile".

So to recap, instead of moving everything inside C:\ECU, I instead need to move everything inside the folder starting with ABCDE. Apologies for being so long winded!

Thanks.

@echo off
for /d /r "c:\ecu" %%a in (Logfile*) do (
if /i "%%~nxa"=="Logfile" (
pushd "%%a"
REM zip all files in the backup directory
 FOR %%A IN (*.TXT* *.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
 FOR %%A IN (*.TXT *.cpi) DO DEL "%%A"
 popd 
)
)

@echo All logfiles zipped. Press Enter to move Project to backup?
pause > nul

xcopy /s "C:\ECU" "C:\Complete"

rename "C:\Complete" %Date:~-10,2%*%Date:~-7,2%*%Date:~-4,4%

pause